# Displaying current list of friends

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing a Friend Request system and currently stuck at one point. I have two tables i.e. `member` and `requests`.  `requests` table stores `user_id` and `friend_id` of two users and I want to display names of current friends that are to be fetched from `member` table. For example, `request` table:

```
request_id | user_id(to) | friend_id(from) | status
2          | 2           | 3               | 1
3          | 3           | 1               | 1
6          | 4           | 2               | 1
7          | 2           | 1               | 1
```

I have achieved the current partners with the query below;

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE user_id='2' OR x.friend_id='2' AND x.status='1'
```

but all I can display for now are id's. What I am trying to achieve is getting the correct **names** according to the id's as well which are stored in the `member` table. Data stored in `member` table is;

```
member_id | name
1         | John
2         | Steve
3         | Sarah
4         | Stuart
```

So, if **id** no. 2 & 3 are friends, the **name** of the **added** friend should be displayed in user's profile who accepted the request.

What I am trying to do:

```
SELECT
    x.*,
    y.* 
FROM
    requests x,
    member y
WHERE 
    x.user_id='$member_id' OR 
    x.friend_id='$member_id' AND
    y.member_id = '$member_id' AND 
    x.status='1'
```

The result of this query gets a list of other members as well regardless of the `member_id` I'd specify. Can anybody please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do when using the [low-level SQL server driver](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using. **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    x.*,
    y.* 
FROM
    requests x
INNER JOIN
    member y ON y.member_id = x.user_id OR y.member_id = x.friend_id
WHERE 
    x.user_id='$member_id' OR 
    x.friend_id='$member_id' AND 
    x.status='1'
```

The INNER JOIN will make it so your query will only return rows that exist in both the requests and member table.

And due to your WHERE clause, this will be limited to only the requests of the $member_id you're passing in.